# agregando un item a items mediante push antes de axios post no envia el item agregado

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Buen dia, gracias de antemano por la ayuda que pudieran darme.
Estoy creando una página de emisión de una factura en laravel con vue y axios.
Antes de mandar a grabar la factura debo verificar si el valor total de la factura le hace acreedor a un premio, que de ser así debe agregarse al detalle de la factura con costo cero (el detalle está en items[]). Si se obtiene el premio se carga a items el premio y envío a grabar a laravel con axios post como pueden ver en el código. El problema que tengo es que a laravel no llega la línea del premio que se cargó al final, solo llegan los que se ingresaron en la página, sin embargo en la página misma si se puede ver que se cargó el premio, ya que vue lo muestra inmediatamente que lo cargo con this.items.push() .

A que se debe que tengo este problema, acaso el axios.post no espera a que complete el método calcular_premio?, tengo que hacer una pausa antes de hacer el axios.post(), no sé que hacer, necesito su ayuda por favor.

Gracias.

```
...
data: {
...
items: []
},
...
calcular_premio: function() {

   if(cumple_condicion) {

       this.items.push({});

   }

},

grabar_factura: function() {

   //antes de grabar la factura verificamos si se hace acreeedor a un premio
   this.calcular_premio();
   //aqui mandamos a grabar mediante una ruta de laravel
   axios.post('/ventas/grabar_venta_ventanilla', ...
```

},

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la solución. En calcular premio utilizo axios.get para en laravel hacer el cálculo del premio. Solo cuando reciba una respuesta, debo hacer la grabación con axios.post. Axios.get se ejecuta y el código continúa su flujo sin esperar a que haya una respuesta. 
Algo asi:

```
calcular_premio: function() {
   axios.get('venta/calcular_premio')
         .then(response => {
            if (response.data.success) {
               this.items.push({});
            }
            axios.post('venta/grabar', ...);
          });  
   //el código siguiente se ejecuta inmediatamente después de axios.get
   //por lo que la grabación debe estar dentro, cuando se reciba respuesta
   ...


}
```